# How do you anchor tons of groups with a script in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been working for so long on a new map spawning in a lot of pine trees. After all my work I noticed the objects in the pine trees weren't anchored I made a group of all the pine trees called "PineTrees" inside there I put a normal script to try to anchor all the objects in the groups. It ended up throwing the error "GetDescendant is not a valid member of Model". Here's the script:

```
local model = script.Parent
local childs = model:GetDescendant() 
for I,v in pairs(childs) do 
    if v:IsA("BasePart") then 
        v.Anchored = true
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply mispelled the [function's name](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetDescendants).

```
local childs = model:GetDescendants()
```